How to manually create an EFI System Partition in Ubuntu 24.04 during installation
Finally available, I downloaded the latest 24.04 LTS Desktop ISO and tried to install it on a test machine. I always choose to manually partition the drive, so I can create separate partitions for the EFI System Partition (ESP), Root (/) and Home (/home).
No matter what i choose, the EFI option is not available under the Partition Type in the  partition creation window. I tried to manually mount a VFAT partition under /boot/efi, but as soon as I create the first partition, of any type, it automatically creates a 1.13 GB EFI partition as the second partition.
I understand this is normal since the 23.10 installer. It's really annoying, an EFI partition should be 100 MB minimum, or typically 512 MB in size. All my tests were done on the same machine, with a 256 NVMe SSD.
Is there a way to manually create it as in the previous LTS (22.04)?

The ubuntu-desktop-installer became default at 23.04 (no change at 23.10 occurred), but if you want a specific partitioning layout, have you tried creating it before hand? (ie. using gparted etc first), and then just selecting the partitions you've already prepared  (I recall doing numerous of these installers, but don't recall watching the ESP except there was/wasn't one as required). The only change I'm aware of is selected partitions can be force-formatted (shown on screen so you're made aware) due to an issue discovered late in QA.

I created a VFAT partition without mount point, a Swap partition and when I created an Ext4 partition, it made a FAT32 partition with size 1.13 GB before that with mount point /boot/efi. Maybe you do not need to create VFAT partition manually.

This question is similar to: No EFI System Partition option for Ubuntu 18.10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is so annoying, I know! I tried even to create the partitions separately but still will fail to use it as boot/efi.
But, I found a way!!!
From the installer, just create on an empty partition table (disk) a single partition (full size) for / (root) the installer will automatically create an empty FAT32 for /boot/efi
... after which you can delete the root partition and do as you wish with the rest.
This is so counter intuitive!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Make the partition, add the esp and boot flags, and format it before you start the 24.04 installation.  If you don't, you find the manual part will not have the critical things like selecting FAT for a fs, EFI for usage, etc.
